# Gather AVX2&512 intrinsic for 16-bit integers?

Tags: optimization, avx2, avx512

Imagine this piece of code:

```
void Function(int16 *src, int *indices, float *dst, int cnt, float mul)
{
    for (int i=0; i<cnt; i++) dst[i] = float(src[indices[i]]) * mul;
};
```

This really asks for gather intrinsics e.g. _mm_i32gather_epi32. I got great success with these when loading floats, but are there any for 16-bit ints? Another problem here is that I need to transition from 16-bits on the input to 32-bits (float) on the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed no instruction to gather 16bit integers, but (assuming there is no risk of memory-access violation) you can just load 32bit integers starting at the corresponding addresses, and mask out the upper halves of each value.
For `uint16_t` this would be a simple bit-and, for signed integers you can shift the values to the left in order to have the sign bit at the most-significant position. You can then (arithmetically) shift back the values before converting them to float, or, since you multiply them anyway, just scale the multiplication factor accordingly.
Alternatively, you could load from two bytes earlier and arithmetically shift to the right. Either way, your bottle-neck will likely be the load-ports (`vpgatherdd` requires 8 load-uops. Together with the load for the indices you have 9 loads distributed on two ports, which should result in 4.5 cycles for 8 elements).

Untested possible AVX2 implementation (does not handle the last elements, if `cnt` is not a multiple of 8 just execute your original loop at the end):

```
void Function(int16_t const *src, int const *indices, float *dst, size_t cnt, float mul_)
{
    __m256 mul = _mm256_set1_ps(mul_*float(1.0f/0x10000));
    for (size_t i=0; i+8<=cnt; i+=8){ // todo handle last elements
        // load indicies:
        __m256i idx = _mm256_loadu_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i const*>(indices + i));
        // load 16bit integers in the lower halves + garbage in the upper halves:
        __m256i values = _mm256_i32gather_epi32(reinterpret_cast<int const*>(src), idx, 2);
        // shift each value to upper half (removes garbage, makes sure sign is at the right place)
        // values are too large by a factor of 0x10000
        values = _mm256_slli_epi32(values, 16);
        // convert to float, scale and multiply:
        __m256 fvalues = _mm256_mul_ps(_mm256_cvtepi32_ps(values), mul);
        // store result
        _mm256_storeu_ps(dst, fvalues);
    } 
}
```

Porting this to AVX-512 should be straight-forward.

Comment: AVX2 `vpgatherdd ymm` on Skylake only costs 4 uops (5c throughput), apparently doing multiple cache accesses per uop.  So the bottleneck isn't execution *ports* or the front-end, and can overlap well with surrounding work better than a `vpinrsw` manual gather.  But yes it does bottleneck on cache read ports or something like that, throughput slightly less than 2 cache reads / clock.  The AVX512 version on SKX is 9c for ZMM, so again 1 extra cycle vs. the 8 you might hope for with 16 cache accesses.  With unaligned dwords, the occasional cache-line split will probably make that worse.

Comment: Nice idea to bake the shift correction scale factor into the float `mul` constant the OP wants to use anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @PeterCordes. I guess I'm misunderstanding the `+8*p23` in https://uops.info/html-instr/VPGATHERDD_YMM_VSIB_YMM_YMM.html -- or is it just a terminology thing (i.e., loading is technically not a µ-op?) The page does indeed say that it requires only 5uops (on Skylake or later), not 11.

Comment: Oh, I was only looking at Agner's guide where he doesn't fully break down the back-end port usage, only which ports and a total number of *front-end* uops.  Yup, `8*p23` does use a back-end load-port uop for every cache access.  That makes more sense.  But somehow it manages to get those uops executed in the back-end without sending that many through the front-end.  That's pretty cool. I wonder if it gets them to replay from the RS in the back-end or something; [the same mechanism](//stackoverflow.com/q/45128763) used to handle cache misses and cache-line splits.

Comment: (There aren't enough front-end uops for micro-fusion to explain it.)  But anyway, yes, it's still true that you can get other ALU uops through the front-end to get ALU work happening in parallel with gathers in the back-end.  This plus not needing any shuffles to combine the dword chunks is what makes gathers useful in some cases.